# How to calculate the theoretical error rate of a two-classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Here is the two Classification problem with the theoretical probability $p$ and $1-p.$

The following graph is the relation between Gini, $\dfrac{1}{2}\times$entropy and error rate. How could we calculate the theoretical error rate for a two-classification?

From the graph, it seems 
$$e(p) = p,\ p\leq0.5;\quad 1-p,\ p>0.5.$$

[image]